# How to pass jq parameter in Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jq

Please help me to resolve this issue.
I am getting issue while executing below commands under steps in jenkinsfile.

steps{

```
            sh "curl -s -L https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64 > ./jq"
            sh "chmod +x ./jq"
            sh "curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-API-Token: xxxxxxxx' 'https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/raghu/${app_name}/release_uploads' >> output_file.json"
            sh "cat output_file.json"

            script{
                upload_id=$(cat output_file.json | jq -r '.upload_id')
                echo "${upload_id}"
            }
        }
```

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: output for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:293)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:269)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:269)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:269)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:25)
    at ***cps.transform***(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8670.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:347)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:259)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:247)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script{
    sh """
        upload_id=\$(cat output_file.json | jq -r '.upload_id')
        echo "\${upload_id}"
    """
}
```

You need to modify the script block as above and also need to escape $-sign to avoid this error. But dont know where you are using `upload_id` and where you are getting `release_url`

Comment: I have used - "jq .upload_id output_file.json"
Output - "6dd41839-xxxxxxxxxxxxx". Can you please suggest how can I store this value in a variable.

Comment: you are already storing it on the shell variable called `upload_id`

Comment: I tried below command  -  1. sh "jq .upload_id output_file.json" > upload_id
                2. upload_id="$(jq .upload_id output_file.json)". Both are throwing error - java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.ShellStep.script expects class java.lang.String but received class java.lang.Boolean

Comment: I dont see any problem with the script block. What is the exact error after these changes? And suggest you add all the sh part inside the script block.

Comment: Its working now - sh "upload_id=\$(jq .upload_id output_file.json)". Lots of thanks for your support :)

Comment: Getting one issue here, value is coming while executing the command , after that its again going back to previous value -"null" -> Command :  sh "upload_id=\$(jq .upload_id output_file.json)"
                echo "upload_id : $upload_id" ; Output : + jq .upload_id output_file.json
+ upload_id="cad1e67b-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
[Pipeline] echo
upload_id : nul.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you format your code and be clear what issue is?. If a variable goes out of scope (not in the same shell session), the value will be lost.